# Random walk- Brownian Motion

Tags: c++, random

I've been assigned the project of creating a simple console app. that models brownian motion in a 2D plane.  I wasn't given much information on how to do so (and I'm hoping that it's a pretty popular assignment so that I could get some insight) just that it relies on random number generation.  I researched brownian motion for a little bit and saw some formulas that looked complicated, but by the description is just seems to have to move randomly within a certain number interval.  Can anyone clarify?  Am I to create a program that continually creates a random number in an interval and then modify the particles "x" and "y" coordinate or is there more to it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What, specifically, have you tried or are you having a problem with?

Comment: This sounds like something to ask your TA.

Comment: Is it full-blown [brownian motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion) or the far-simpler [random walk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk)? Will you have to migrate the program from random walk to Brownian motion in the next iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that the random motion is not "uniform", but rather if you plot the frequency of movements vs movement distance you'll see that most are short, some are longer, and a few are very long, creating something resembling an exponential decline.

I can't remember what statistical curve the motion observes, but you can probably figure that out, and then you need to craft a random number generator that generates values to fit that curve.

What I would do is calculate distance using this RNG, then use a uniform RNG to calculate angle, from zero to 2*pi, and make the motion polar.  You could calculate a random X and a random Y separately, but I'm not sure you'd get the same distribution.

Comment: Yep, bdares had the distribution -- Gaussian.  (Haven't thought about this stuff since 1972.)  There are RNGs that will compute Gaussian random numbers directly (or at least there were in 1972).

Comment: C++ has a gaussian distribution for use with its random number library. It's called `std::normal_distribution`.

Answer (score 3):

Brownian motion is the result of random air molecules hitting a small particle.  Since the sum of a bunch of random forces is unlikely to be exactly 0, and the mass of the particle is so small, it appears to jiggle around, hence Brownian motion.  So you get a motion that appears random, but is not uniformly so.

The dumb way to model it would be to get a uniform distribution for the direction and Gaussian distribution for the momentum of hundreds of air molecules, apply collisions to a particle, and get the sum.  Do this many times and you'll get Brownian-type motion.  (The individual air molecules have an average momentum dependent on the temperature, and the number of air molecules is dependent on the pressure.)

Note that the resulting motion is not Gaussian, but rather the sum of many samples from the Gaussian distribution.  Not sure what it's called.

Comment: Shouldn't the sum of many samples from the Gaussian (normal) distribution be Gaussian itself? By the central limit theorem, the sampling distribution of the sample mean of *any* distribution approaches the normal distribution as the number of samples grows without bound.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is horribly ill-posed. This almost certainly isn't your fault since your instructor should have pointed out to you that a proper implementation of Brownian motion requires lots and lots of pretty sophisticated specification and analysis of the problem domain even before you get to coding.

The precise definition of Brownian motion is probably going to be opaque to you unless you've taken the relevant courses in measure theory. However, there are plenty of resources on the net that give adequate descriptions of Ito processes (of which Brownian motion is an example).

If you're interested in coding such a process up, here's a decent tip. At some stage you're going to need to generate random numbers. Almost certainly, you're going to be interested in generating draws from a normal distribution. Thankfully, there are some great ways of doing this available to a C++ programmer. My favourite is to use the Boost.Random library (or the relevant libraries in C++11). The smartest strategy is to use a function object to generate the random variates, probably by using a variate_generator:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/normal_distribution.hpp>
#include <boost/random/variate_generator.hpp>

int main()
{
  // Some typedefs to help keep the code clean
  // Always a good idea when using Boost!
  typedef boost::mt19937                                      T_base_prng;
  typedef boost::normal_distribution<>                        T_norm_varg;
  typedef boost::variate_generator<T_base_prng&, T_norm_dist> T_norm_varg;

  unsigned int base_seed = 42;  // Seed for the base pseudo-random number generator
  double       mean      = 0.0; // Mean of the normal distribution
  double       stdev     = 1.0; // Standard deviation of the normal distribution
  T_base_prng  base_prng(base_seed); // Base PRNG
  T_norm_dist  norm_dist(mean, stdev); // Normal distribution
  T_norm_varg  norm_varg(base_prng, norm_dist); // Variate generator

  // Generate 1000 draws from a standard normal distribution
  vector<double> drawVec(1000);
  for (vector<double>::iterator iter = drawVec.begin(); 
       iter != drawVec.end(); ++iter)
  {
    *iter = norm_varg();
  }

  // More stuff...


  return 0;
}
```

Once you get a handle on what a Brownian motion is, it should then be trivial to construct some examples using the functionality in Boost.Random.

Comment: Probably better for the example to use the standard library rather than boost.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you only need to add the random number to the `x` and `y` coordinates at each time step as follow:

```
int x=0, y=0;

for (int t=0; t<N; t++) {
    x += distribution(gen);
    y += distribution(gen);
    display(x, y);
}
```

where the distribution can be simple as `{0,1}` , a interval, or a Guassian distribution.

**Edit:** For very large N, you can measure whether the mean distance `R = d(x,y)` and check whether it is scaled like `t ~ R^2`. Surely, the above code only generate one Brownian motion, in order for the relationship to hold, you have to repeat many time. Do the experiment yourself.

Comment: Do note that we like to avoid giving pre-written code directly in response to [tag:homework] questions. (Not that this is drop-in ready, but at least bdares and Hot Licks have further raised the issue of which distribution specifically to pick that I feel they are superior answers.)

Comment: This is not true.  How far a Brownian process moves within an interval follows a Gaussian distribution.

Comment: @ApprenticeQueue: It is statistically true only when the N is very large. For small `N`, you can tell whether it is a Brownian motion